# Can not read property of undefined for replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I have a web app which runs on bootstrap 3 and angular 1.3. When I run my grunt task, it gives me the following error:

```css
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined    bowerComponets.min.js :5

And it probably at this line: replace(rd,function(a,c){return(c?b:"")+a.toLowerCase()})}
```

My bower.json:

```css
{
  "name": "myWebApp",
  "version": "0.0.1a",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.28",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.28",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.28",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.28",
    "angular-busy": "~4.1.2",
    "angular-touch": "~1.2.28",
    "angular-translate": "~2.7.0",
    "ui-router": "~0.2.11",
    "wdpr-angular-router": ">0.0.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.0",
    "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
    "wdpr-angular-logger": ">0.0.0",
    "wdpr-angular-error-handler": ">0.0.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.8.0",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "~0.2.6",
    "respond": "~1.4.2",
    "html5shiv": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular-animate": "~1.3",
    "angular": "~1.3",
 "bootstrap":"~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: the reason for the error is the variable is undefined,can you please create a fiddle or post your full code

Comment: To create fiddle, this is the bower issue. Huge web app. How can I create min.js fiddle? Sorry.